# Marketing Cloud "Email Sends" related list is not populating but "Individual Email Results" is

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a question regarding the IER and Email Sends related list within the CRM after completing the MCC implementation.

When testing the connector - I created an email send to a report (the report had 1 lead record) and once completed, I requested the tracking data and when i viewed my Lead record, the IER related list was populated, but the Email Sends related list was not - see attached.

[image]

Per my understanding, both related lists would populate, but IER would have the results (i.e. email was opened at xyz time) is my understanding wrong? If i sent to a report, should it not be populating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send an marketing cloud email via salesforce report only the individual Email results will get updated.

Email sends related list count will get updated only when you send an email by clicking the link - "Send Marketing Cloud Email". Please refer the below screenshot:

[image]